# Exponentiating Matrices - Am I doing it correctly?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

I recently learned how to exponentiate matrices by extending the power series of $e^x$ to matrices:
$$e^A=A^0+A^1+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!}+...$$
I thought that this was pretty cool, so I decided to try it with the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
I then realized that I would have to find a general formula for $A^n$. I ended up getting
$$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}2^{n-1}&2^{n-1}\\2^{n-1}&2^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
for $n\ge 1$, and for $n=0$, I have that $A^0=I$. So my final answer would be in the form
$$e^A=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\alpha-1\\\alpha-1&\alpha\end{pmatrix}$$
where
$$\alpha=1+2^0+\frac{2^1}{2!}+\frac{2^2}{3!}+...$$
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+2^0+2^1+\frac{2^2}{2!}+\frac{2^3}{3!}+...\bigg)$$
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{2}(e^2+1)$$
and so my answer would be
$$e^A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{e^2+1}{2}&\frac{e^2-1}{2}\\\frac{e^2-1}{2}&\frac{e^2+1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Why the self-doubt? If you have proved it, isn't that enough?

Comment: @JohnColeman I just want to make sure that I'm doing it correctly. It would not be good if I did it wrong a whole bunch of times because I thought I was doing it correctly to begin with.

Comment: You may want to justify saying $A^0=I$ when this is not the same as your expression for $A^n$ when $n=0$

Comment: @Henry Oh. I thought that $A^0=I$ was just true by convention?

Comment: I would prefer starting from $\exp(A)=I+A^1+\frac{1}{2!}A^2+\frac{1}{3!}A^3+\cdots$ so you only need to consider positive integer powers of a matrix with a determinant of $0$.  You then get your result

Comment: @Nilknarf Of course it is reasonable to want confirmation that you are using a defintion correctly. But somewhat often on Math Overflow, I see examples of perfectly correct reasoning by someone who is seeking confirmation of the correctness of that reasoning and I wonder why they are even posting. I sometimes get the impression that not everyone trusts the certainty that mathematics can confer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Oh, don't worry - I trust the certainty of mathematics. However, it is the *un*certainty of my own flawed human nature that makes me doubt my answer.

Comment: Looks ok to me. I used the same eigenvalue trick as Jose Carlos Santos to verify. If you want to try one more, I recommend
$$A=\pmatrix{0&-x\cr x&0\cr}.$$ Hint: with $x=1$ we have what is known as an infinitesimal generator of the group of rotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is correct, as you've been told. But here's another way of doing this that may interest you. Let$$M=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$Then$$M^{-1}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }M^{-1}.A.M=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Therefore$$M^{-1}.e^A.M=e^{\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}}=\begin{pmatrix}e^2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$So,$$e^A=M.\begin{pmatrix}e^2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.M^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{e^2+1}{2}&\frac{e^2-1}{2}\\\frac{e^2-1}{2}&\frac{e^2+1}{2}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ooh, interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean when you ask whether you are "doing it correctly."

If you're asking whether you computed the exponential for *this* matrix correctly, the answer is yes.

If you're asking whether this is a general method to use for an arbitrary matrix, the answer is a resounding no: it will be impossible to determine a formula for $A^n$ just by inspection or multiplying out a few terms (which I assume you did here).

One general method for diagonalizable matrices is to first diagonalize $A$, because the exponential of a diagonal matrix is easy. (This is what José did.)

If the matrix isn't diagonalizable, you can do the next best thing and put it in Jordan normal form; it is also easy to work out the exponential of Jordan blocks.

Computationally, however, the problem is very delicate. See [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=513F66BCD5ABFCE2385CC7E902440269?doi=10.1.1.92.5653&rep=rep1&type=pdf), "Nineteen Dubious Ways to Calculate the Exponential of a Matrix," for example.